# What's the best way to filter text length of last Textview in Android

Tags: android, text

I have limited the length of Textview2.

textview2.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(2) });

Textview1               = 456789

So Textview2 is display = 45

I want to display only last two text ( 89 ).

How to filter text length?

Thank all.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible with `InputFilter.LengthFilter`.

```java
int length = textview2.length();
textView2.setText(textview2.getText().toString().substring(length - 2, length))
```

Comment: I hope it to helpful to you :)